# What is the correct way to pass array elements to TikZ styles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to use styles to generate *TikZ* figures that have repeated, regularly spaced elements by looping through an array, but am perplexed by the results I'm getting.

For example, if I define the style

```
state/.style={circle,draw=none,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:$#1$,name=#1}
```

then when I try to iterate through an array as the source of the arguments to the style, as in

```
\def\labels{{e,a,a^2,a^3}};\def\dim{4};
\foreach \n in {0,1,2,3} {
    \node[state={\labels[\n]}]at({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};}
```

I get an error: *Package pgf Error: No shape named e is known.*

If I change around the definition of the array and the iterator(s)a bit,

```
\def\nodes{0/{e},1/{a},2/{a^2},3/{a^3}};\def\dim{4};
\foreach \n\lab in \nodes{
    \node[state={\lab}]at({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};}
```

I can get the result I want (see MWE), but I'd rather not do this, as it requires an array structure that's not generally useable for my purposes.

[image]

How can I get the first form of the iterator and array to work?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{petri}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    redarrow/.style={->, red, fill=none,>=stealth, thick},
    state/.style={circle,draw=gray,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:$#1$,name=#1}}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% This approach results in an error
% \def\labels{{e,a,a^2,a^3}};\def\dim{4};
% \foreach \n in {0,1,2,3} {
%   \node[state={\labels[\n]}]at({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};}
\def\nodes{0/{e},1/{a},2/{a^2},3/{a^3}};\def\dim{4};
\foreach \n\lab in \nodes{
    \node[state={\lab}]at({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};}
\draw[redarrow](e)--(a);\draw[redarrow](a)--(a^2);\draw[redarrow](a^2)--(a^3);\draw[redarrow](a^3)--(e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another version of this scenario produces an odd result: if I change the order of the approaches above, I no longer get the error, but instead get a figure that ["uses" the elements defined in the first figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56831/7844), and gives them labels like "e,a,a^2,a^3[0]".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

Sorry I did not know that `pgfmath` could work with arrays. The problem is that you need to use "e", "a" etc.. because "pgfmath" replaces `e` by 2.71828, and says that `a` is not a math function.

Don't forgot the next two rules.

> Each element in the array will be evaluated as it is parsed, so
>   expressions can be used.

and

> "x" (group operators) These operators are used to quote x. However, as
>   every expression is expanded with \edef before it is parsed, macros
>   (e.g., font commands like \tt or \Huge) may need to be “protected”
>   from this expansion (e.g., \noexpand\Huge). Ideally, you should avoid
>   such macros anyway. Obviously, these operators should be used with
>   great care as further calculations are unlikely to be possible with
>   the result.

A solution is the next code but I don't like the node's names perhaps simpler is to use `\n` for the names.

remark : the result of `\pgfmathparse{\labels[\n]}` is given by `\pgfmathresult` and it's possible in some cases, to store this result with another macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    redarrow/.style 2 args={->, red, fill=none,>=stealth, thick},
    state/.style={circle,draw=gray,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:#1}}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\dim{4}
￼\def\labels{{"e","a","a^2","a^3"}}
\foreach \n in  {0,...,3}{
\pgfmathparse{\labels[\n]} 
\node[state={$\pgfmathresult$}] (\pgfmathresult) at ({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};
  }   

\draw[redarrow](e)--(a);\draw[redarrow](a)--(a^2);\draw[redarrow](a^2)--(a^3);\draw[redarrow](a^3)--(e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

also possible is

```
\tikzset{
    redarrow/.style 2 args={->, red, fill=none,>=stealth, thick},
    state/.style={circle,draw=gray,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:$#1$,name=#1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\dim{4}
￼\def\labels{{"e","a","a^2","a^3"}}
\foreach \n in  {0,...,3}{
\pgfmathparse{\labels[\n]} 
\node[state={\pgfmathresult}]  at ({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};
  }   
\draw[redarrow](e)--(a);\draw[redarrow](a)--(a^2);\draw[redarrow](a^2)--(a^3);\draw[redarrow](a^3)--(e);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

**First answer :**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{state/.style={circle,
                       draw=gray,
                       inner sep=0pt,
                       minimum size=7mm,
                       label=center:$#1$,
                       name=#1}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\labels{e,a,a^2,a^3}\def\dim{4}
\foreach \n [count=\ni] in \labels {% 
  \node[state={\n}] at ({cos(90+\ni*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\ni*(360/\dim))}){};}  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was building from the example on the top of p.529 of the TikZ-PGF manual (v. 2.10). Where did I go wrong in adapting that?

Comment: Ha ! there is an array structure inside pgfmath. I think you need to access values of the array with `pgfmathparse`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for keeping the old answer too for reference. That was also quite helpful.