# What is the scope of elements of TikZ pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, grouping

I understand that named elements of a `tikzpicture` cannot be referenced before they are defined; but I'm confused about how "long" a named element persists. It appears that once named, an element continues to exist, even *in (subsequent) pictures that do not contain the element*.

For example, the code

```
\draw[bluearrow](e)--(r);
```

generates the expected "undefined element" error if used prior to the definition of 'e' and 'r', but once I create a picture containing code that defines these elements, subsequent figures containing exactly the code above will no longer produce an error, and will instead draw the requested arrow, between the locations in that figure corresponding to the locations of 'e' and 'r' in the original figure in which they were defined:

[image]

What is the default scope of `tikzpicture` element names? Is there a way to control their scope? The (apparent) default behavior seems likely to produce hard to debug behavior in figures.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{petri}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    bluearrow/.style={->, blue, fill=none,>=stealth', thick},
    state/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7mm,label=center:$#1$,name=#1}}

\begin{center}

% This fails here ...
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[bluearrow](e)--(a);\draw[bluearrow](a)--(a^2);\draw[bluearrow](a^2)--(a^3);\draw[bluearrow](a^3)--(e);
%\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\nodes{0/{e},1/{r},2/{r^2},3/{r^3}};\def\dim{4};
\foreach \n\lab in \nodes{
    \node[state={\lab}]at({cos(90+\n*(360/\dim))},{sin(90+\n*(360/\dim))}){};}
\draw[bluearrow](e)--(r);\draw[bluearrow](r)--(r^2);\draw[bluearrow](r^2)--(r^3);\draw[bluearrow](r^3)--(e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{10 mm}

% ... but it works fine here.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[bluearrow](e)--(r);\draw[bluearrow](r)--(r^2);\draw[bluearrow](r^2)--(r^3);\draw[bluearrow](r^3)--(e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TikZ itself adds a lot of internal groups, e.g. every `\path ...;` command is a TeX group. Because `\node` is basically just `\path node` the node name can not be defined locally because it would not survive it's own definition scope!
While there are some techniques getting a macro out of a scope using such for *every node* (which is defined as a set of several macro) at *every group* inside a `tikzpicture` is just not doable. Therefore nodes etc. are **defined globally**, which makes them accessible for the rest of the document, even in other `tikzpictures`. The position of the node relative to the current origin should still be valid, so you could define `\coordinate (my offset) at (1,1);` in one `tikzpicture` and still use it in other ones. 
If you however want to draw directly to the *original* coordinate/node then `remember picture,overlay` is required.

Comment: Though I worry about debugging, I suppose (and can imagine) that there are scenarios in which this could be *very* useful.