# How can I inhibit expansion through several layers of \edef?

Tags: expansion, pgfmath

I'm using a macro I've defined based on [some suggestions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47649/7844) here to automate the creation of tables.

For example something like

```
\newcommand{\clearrows}{\let\matrixcontent\empty}
\newcommand{\actionsrow}[3]{%
  \foreach \i in #3 {%
    \pgfmathparse{#1[\i-1]}
    \let\c\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{#2[\i-1]}
    \let\s\pgfmathresult
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\matrixcontent{\noexpand\node[\s]{\c}; \&}}\x
    }%
  \gappto\matrixcontent{\\}%
}
```

lets me easily create the tables I need, with a few lines of code. For example,

```
\newcommand{\rowhv}[1]{
    \actionsrow{{"$e$","$h$","$v$","$hv$"}}{{{"fill=gray!3"},{"fill=gray!33"},{"fill=gray!67"},{"fill=gray!100"}}}{#1} }
\clearrows
\rowhv{{1,2,3,4}} \rowhv{{2,1,4,3}} \rowhv{{3,4,1,2}} \rowhv{{4,3,2,1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,nodes={minimum size=7mm}]{\matrixcontent};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image]

which may not seem like much of an accomplishment, but I need to build quite large tables, and a lot of them, so these macros are essential.

I need to be able to put arbitrary content in the cells, ranging from arbitrary formatting (e.g., `\textsf{..}`) to imported images  (using, for example, `\includegraphics`) or other macros I define to draw node contents. But the code  above only works for cell contents that are plain text. If I supply anything other other than plain text among the items in the first argument to `\actionsrow`, which is used for `\c` in the loop there, I get an error,

> Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.

even though such content is perfectly valid for nodes. I suspect there's something going on with the way my (pilfered) macro is parsing `\c`, but I don't even know where to begin track that down.

How can I modify my `\actionsrow` macro so that I can specify arbitrary LaTeX as contents for my nodes?

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}

% See -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47649/7844
\newcommand{\clearrows}{\let\matrixcontent\empty}
\newcommand{\actionsrow}[3]{%
  \foreach \i in #3 {%
    \pgfmathparse{#1[\i-1]} % See -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56838/7844; note \let vs \def
    \let\c\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{#2[\i-1]}
    \let\s\pgfmathresult
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\matrixcontent{\noexpand\node[\s]{\c}; \&}}\x
    }%
  \gappto\matrixcontent{\\}%
}

% This works fine
\newcommand{\rowhv}[1]{
    \actionsrow{{"$e$","$h$","$v$","$hv$"}}{{{"fill=gray!3"},{"fill=gray!33"},{"fill=gray!67"},{"fill=gray!100"}}}{#1} }
\clearrows
\rowhv{{1,2,3,4}} \rowhv{{2,1,4,3}} \rowhv{{3,4,1,2}} \rowhv{{4,3,2,1}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,nodes={minimum size=7mm}]{\matrixcontent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

% Here, arbitrary specifications work for the nodes, if done manually
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [nodes={minimum size=7mm}]
{
    \node[fill=gray!3]{\texttt{e}}; & \node[fill=gray!33]{\color{red}$h$}; & \node[fill=gray!67]{$v$}; & \node[fill=gray!100]{$hv$}; \\
    \node[fill=gray!33]{\color{red}$h$}; & \node[fill=gray!3]{\texttt{e}}; & \node[fill=gray!100]{$hv$}; & \node[fill=gray!67]{$v$}; \\
    \node[fill=gray!67]{$v$}; & \node[fill=gray!100]{$hv$}; & \node[fill=gray!3]{\texttt{e}}; & \node[fill=gray!33]{\color{red}$h$}; \\
    \node[fill=gray!100]{$hv$}; & \node[fill=gray!67]{$v$}; & \node[fill=gray!33]{\color{red}$h$}; & \node[fill=gray!3]{\texttt{e}}; \\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

% But this fails
\renewcommand{\rowhv}[1]{
    \actionsrow{{"\texttt{e}","\color{red}$h$","$v$","$hv$"}}{{{"fill=gray!3"},{"fill=gray!33"},{"fill=gray!67"},{"fill=gray!100"}}}{#1} }
\clearrows
\rowhv{{1,2,3,4}} \rowhv{{2,1,4,3}} \rowhv{{3,4,1,2}} \rowhv{{4,3,2,1}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&,nodes={minimum size=7mm}]{\matrixcontent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

￼\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate help titling and tagging this question: I may not have the source of my problem properly identified.

Comment: I've changed them to what seems to be an accurate description of the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems, both with `\edef`.  The second one is literally with your `\edef`, as any macro inside `#1` that finds its way into `\c` will be expanded into `\x` and create chaos.  The first one is with `\pgfmathparse`, as according to the manual, everything in a math expression is fully expanded, and therefore, you will require extra protection for things that should *not* be expanded.  I see two ways around this:

1. Put `\unexpanded` around every item in array `#1` manually, and also put `\expandonce` in front of `\c` inside that `\edef` (so it is expanded but its contents are not).  This is a pain but will fix the problem.
2. Do a preliminary loop with `\foreach` to put in those `\unexpanded`s before continuing with the current body of `\actionsrow`.  Since it will be a pain to get the double quotes to interact well with this, I suggest you make the syntax for its first argument `{$a$, $\mathbf{b}$, \includegraphics{c.pdf}, ...}`, *without* the quotes, and have `\foreach` add both the `\unexpanded` and the quotes.  Also, don't forget `\expandonce\c` in the `\edef`, as before.

Here is how I implemented option 2:

```
\newcommand{\actionsrow}[3]{%
  %%%
  % NEW STUFF
  %%%
  \let\comma=\empty
  \let\b=\empty
  \foreach \a in {#1} {%
   \xappto\b{\comma"\noexpand\unexpanded{\expandonce\a}"}%
   \gdef\comma{,}%
  }%
  \foreach \i in #3 {%
    %%% CHANGED #1 -> \b
    \pgfmathparse{{\b}[\i-1]}%
    \let\c\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{#2[\i-1]}%
    \let\s\pgfmathresult
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       %%% ADDED \expandonce\c
       \noexpand\gappto\noexpand\matrixcontent{\noexpand\node[\s]{\expandonce\c}; \&}}\x
    }%
  \gappto\matrixcontent{\\}%
}

\newcommand{\rowhv}[1]{
 \actionsrow
  %%% NEW SYNTAX: first arg is a pure CSV list
  {$\mathbf{e}$,$h$,$v$,$hv$}
  {{{"fill=gray!3"},{"fill=gray!33"},{"fill=gray!67"},{"fill=gray!100"}}}
  {#1}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does a great job. I still have some issues with certian arguments (e.g. `\color{..}`: "Undefined color 'r'"). It also looks like I need to do some reading on how expansion works.

Comment: What problems are you having with color?  If I put `\color{red}` into the `$h$`, for example, it works just fine.

Comment: Interesting: it works inside the `$..$`, but not outside: `\color{red}h` and `\color{red}$h$` fail, but `\color{red}$h$` works.

Comment: I also don't seem to be able to provide any arguments that use the `scope` environment (e.g. many figures I'd like do draw and place in the cells).

Comment: This seems to be a problem (likely a bug) with the way `pgfmath` treats arrays.  Try `\pgfmathparse{{"{red}a", "b"}[0]}\pgfmathresult` and cringe at the result.  It actually catches the "nested array" `{red}`; apparently, *no* braces are safe in array elements.